# Awk and dollar sign in record separator

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to parse a file that has, for whatever reason, the string "&($)" as record separator and "(@)$" as a field separator. I couldn't get awk to parse the file by specifying these as RS and FS in the BEGIN block. I'm using gnu awk 3.1.7 and it complains saying that there's a syntax error but couldn't find how to escape the dollar sign (assuming that's what it doesn't like).

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="(@)$" RS="&($)"} {} END{print NR}' some-file.txt
awk: BEGIN{FS="(@)$" RS="&($)"} {} END{print NR}
awk:                   ^ syntax error
```

Appreciate help from the experts.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need escape those chars with special meaning in regex.

```
kent$  cat f                                               
foo(@)$bar(@)$blah&($)foo2(@)$bar2(@)$blah2

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\(@\\)\\$";RS="&\\(\\$\\)"}{print NR,NF}' f
1 3
2 3
```

Comment: Note that the necessary `;` was added in this answer, although not explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

As you are defining two values in the `BEGIN{}` block, you are missing a semi colon to separate them:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="(@)$"; RS="&($)"} {} END{print NR}' file
                    ^
```

You can also do

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="(@)$"} {} END{print NR}' RS="&($)" file
```

---

Regarding the use of these separators, note as well what [Kent is commenting in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667139/1983854): you need to escape them.

```
$ cat a
hello(@)$this(@)$is one record&($)and this another one
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\(\\@\\)\\$"} {print $1, NR, NF}' RS="\\&\\(\\$\\)" a
hello 1 3
and this another one
 2 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is gonna parse the file as OP described.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I focused on the FS/RS declaration and then checked the rest.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I had a tried with this, but forgot to include in the question.